# The Servosix board doesn't seem to stop servo jitter

Tags: servo

I just received the Servosix kit from Pi Hut, which is basically a [Servosix board](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/3274/files/instructions_servo_six.pdf?v=1589990518) and two SG-90 servo motors.

The board's purpose is to easily control servo motors, without the usual jitter associated with them.

Well as it happens, I do have that jitter, as demonstrated [here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/iDYPzMyqTL9graQG6).

I am using the code that they tell you to use in the board's instructions.

```
from gpiozero import AngularServo
from guizero import App, Slider

servo = AngularServo(17, min_pulse_width=0.5/1000, max_pulse_width=2.5/1000)

def slider_changed(angle):
 servo.angle = int(angle)

app = App(title='Servo Angle', width=500, height=150)
slider = Slider(app, start=-90, end=90, command=slider_changed, width='fill', height=50)
slider.text_size = 30
app.display()
```

where 17 is the GPIO pin.

Would anyone with servo experience mind giving me their two cents? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The board seems to be a convenient way of connecting servos.  It does nothing to prevent servo jitter.

If you want to prevent servo jitter you need accurately timed servo pulses.  The way to achieve this is to use pigpio as the gpiozero backend.

See https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html#pin-factories for how to select the pin factory.

You can test directly with pigpio.

`sudo pigpiod`

then

```
pigs s 17 2000
pigs s 17 1000
pigs s 17 1500
```

Comment: Indeed, pigpio did the trick. I used some code found in the description of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Rli9Wd2Skc).

Thanks Joan!